# AJAX request before regular form is being submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a jQuery form validation script that is executed while user is trying to submit. I would like another function with AJaX request to be executed (and completed) after the form is validated but before it is sent.

Here is the script. The *zglosip* function works okay when called separately; i.e. not from inside the `submit()` function.

**zglosip(); (function that I want to be called)**

```
function zglosip() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'res/php/nZglos.php',
            data : {
            "erepid" : "111",
            "ip" : "222",
            "poz" : "333"
            },
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            tempor.html(data);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            tempor.html(errorThrown);
            },
            dataType : 'text'
            return true;
        });
    };
```

validation script (created by **Joren Rapini** and modified by me)

pole & tempor are variables containing names of some divs

```
$("#forml").submit(function(){  
    //Validate required fields
    if ((pole.val() == "") || (pole.val() == blad)) {
        pole.addClass("podkresl");
        pole.val(blad);
    } else {
        pole.removeClass("podkresl");
    }
    // Validate the e-mail.
    if (!/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/.test(pole.val())) {
        pole.addClass("podkresl");
        pole.val(blad);
    }


    if ($(":input").hasClass("podkresl")) {
        return false;
    } else {
      if (zglosip() == true) {
          return true
      }
    }
});
```

As you have already found out, I had tried to return true of the `submit()` function after the `zglosIp()` returned true (the if statement at bottom of the script). This did not work unfortunately, I have also tried calling `zglosip()` with separate `function{return true}` in it but surely I have not used it properly.
Please help me.

Comment: tempor.html(data); shoud be $("#tempor").html(data); and you should have <div id="tempor"></div>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to first ensure the form is not being submitted, then run your ajax call, and if the call is successful, proceed to submit. Note I removed the ajax call from zgoslip and put it in the submit handler for the form. you can restructure it the way you want:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { 

     // this code prevents form from actually being submitted
     e.preventDefault();
     e.returnValue = false;

     // some validation code here: if valid, add podkres1 class

     if ($('input.podkres1').length > 0) { 
        // do nothing
     } else {

        var $form = $(this);

        // this is the important part. you want to submit
        // the form but only after the ajax call is completed
         $.ajax({ 
             type: 'post',
             url: someUrl, 
             context: $form, // context will be "this" in your handlers
             success: function() { // your success handler
             },
             error: function() { // your error handler
             },
             complete: function() { 
                // make sure that you are no longer handling the submit event; clear handler
                this.off('submit');
                // actually submit the form
                this.submit();
             }
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: Contents of zglosip() function can be as you did it, that is okay. Thanks to your comments I understand how does the code works (I think so, at least :)). And I have an additional question: code after complete: will execute both when ajax call will succeed and when it fails? The onlly condition is that the call is complete, am I right? Edit: Okay, found it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have a question: could you shortly explain me, why does the form not redirect anywhere after submitting? Or at could you tell me which part of the code should I study more to know that?
By the way, it is okay; even better; that submitting the form does not redirect me anywhere :)

Comment: The form doesn't redirect because of the two lines:

    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

It prevents the default action from happening. (hence `preventDefault`).

The code above should clear the "submit" event handlers for that form and resubmit it after the ajax call is completed. That's done in the 2 lines in the complete handler.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. 'this' is not recognized in complete as a object which contain off and submit functions, so I replaced 'this' by $form, but in that case my real submit is marked as cancelled (Network tab in Chrome) and redirect will not take a place.

Comment: couldn't this all be prevented by making ajax request synchorous. I think event fires before form is actually sent so sync request is made it will automatically delay going to next page.

Comment: I used $("#frm") instead of using this (i.e. this.off('submit') or this.submit()) in the complete function. Because this was pointing to the ajax call object instead of the form.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove the submit type from the button and then I had to call a method that checked the validity of the data I had to submit.

```
<input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" id="submitbutton" />
```

Then I wrote a method  that does the check and returns true if I have to stop and ask to continue:

```
 public ActionResult CheckBeforeSubbmission(datatype  var1)
 {
    if(var1>0)
         return Json(new { result1 = true });
    else
        return Json(new { result1 = false });
 }
```

After that I added the javascript/ajax the code below:

```
  $("#submitbutton").click(function (e) {

        var self = $('#form');
        //A value from the form to post to the controller
        var var1 = $('#var1elementid').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/SomeController/CheckBeforeSubbmission",
            data: {
                var1: var1
            },success: function (response) {
                if (response.result1) {
                    bootbox.confirm({
                        message: "The check failed! Do you want to submit?",
                        buttons: {
                            confirm: {
                                label: 'Yes',
                                className: 'btn-success'
                            },
                            cancel: {
                                label: 'Cancel',
                                className: 'btn-danger'
                            }
                        },
                        callback: function (result) {
                            if (result) {
                                self.submit();
                            } else {
                                bootbox.hideAll();
                                return false;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    self.submit();
                }
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
```